# Problema al grabar con Radiobutton

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
Label(frame, text = 'Apellidos: ').grid(row =2, column = 0, pady = 10)
self.apellido1 = Entry(frame)
self.apellido1.grid(row =2, column = 1, padx = 10)

self.apellido2 = Entry(frame)
self.apellido2.focus()
self.apellido2.grid(row =2, column = 2, padx = 10)
```

Acá introduzco los datos del sexo con un Radiobutton

```
 self.sexo1 = Entry(frame)
 Label(frame, text = 'Sexo: ').grid(row =3, column = 0, pady = 10)
 rad1=Radiobutton(frame, text="Masculino", variable=self.sexo1, value='Maculino')
 rad2=Radiobutton(frame, text="Femenino", variable=self.sexo1, value='Femenino')
 rad1.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)
 rad2.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=10)
```

Acá tengo la función para grabar los datos introducidos

```
def agregar_productos(self):
    if self.validation():
        query = 'INSERT INTO escuela VALUES(null, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
        parameters = (self.nombre1.get(), self.nombre2.get(), self.apellido1.get(), 
                     self.apellido2.get(), self.sexo1.get(), self.fecha1.get(), self.dias1.get())
        self.run_query(query, parameters) 
        messagebox.showinfo("A T E N C I O N ! ! !", "El estudiante fue agregado con exito!")
        self.nombre1.delete(0, END)
        self.nombre2.delete(0, END)
        self.apellido1.delete(0, END)
        self.apellido2.delete(0, END)
        self.fecha1=''
        self.dia1=''
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning('A T E N C I O N ! ! !', 'Registro NO agregado, Se requiere de un 
        NOMBRE y un APELLIDO')
    self.get_products()
```

Mi problema es que no me graba nada, el campo sexo1 queda en blanco, no genera ningún error, y el botón funciona bien en pantalla, pero no graba en la tabla queda en blanco, agradezco me ayuden a ubicar el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que si cambias esta variable de tipo de dato y al `Entry` cámbialo a otra variable que no sea la misma que ocupas para los radiobutton.

```
self.sexo1 = StringVar()
```

Comment: Gracias Eduardo Dela cruz, funciono la respuesta, muy agradecido